# Deploying SampleCrowdsale with openzeppelin - Error: invalid address

Tags: token, ethereum, openzeppelin

I am trying to deploy this SampleCrowdsale example from open-zeppelin
[SampleCrowdsale](https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-contracts/blob/master/contracts/examples/SampleCrowdsale.sol)

It requires the following inputs to deploy:

```
openingTime:
closingTime:
rate:
wallet:<address>
cap:
token:<address>
goal:
```

What are the token and wallet addresses here? I am only trying to deploy it to Ganache through Metamask.

Answer (score 0):

The wallet is just one of your accounts (auto-generated by Ganache)
The token is a `ERC20Mintable` token contract, which you need to create first. See the other example how to instantiate a token but you need to make it mintable as well by adding that to the `is` list.

Hope this helps!

Comment: What is the significance of the wallet? Does the ether used to buy the tokens go to this account? Also, do I need to deploy 2 contracts then? First deploy a token contract and then use its address as an input while deploying the SampleCrowdsale contract?